# Which AWS AMI should I use for Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.04, and run node.js?

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I am looking for a simple AWS Image, (Instance Storage), that is something like a barebone, running Ubuntu 10.04 or 11.04, 64bit.

I'm going to run Node.js on it.  so, I don't need apache, nor nginx.

anyone know which image I should use?  there are too many and causing me headache. LOL

Comment: What does AWS stand for?

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to search for one in this link: http://thecloudmarket.com/ - you can search and use  filters to narrow down your exact - it's worth giving it a try.

I would suggest choosing one from these alestic or scalr owners - they are good. Try this scalr's Ubuntu 10.04 (these does not have anything other than what Linux OS needs rest you have to install):

http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-fc13e495--szr-lamp-ubuntu1004-x86-64-ebs-1

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any trouble getting node installed and running on an Amazon Linux instance.  I'm sure it would be slightly easier if a binary package was available, but it's pretty easy to build and install from source (and you'll need gcc + libraries for many of the packages available via npm anyway).